# Replace all commas in a string with JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a form where I have a couple hundred text boxes and I'd like to remove any commas when they are loaded and prevent commas from being entered. Shouldn't the follow code work assuming the selector is correct?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[id*=_tb]")
  .each(function () {
      this.value.replace(",", "")
  })
  .onkeyup(function () {
      this.value.replace(",", "") 
  })
});
```

Comment: Did you try the above code, and if so, what was the outcome?

Comment: nearly right, see this: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-replace

Comment: I'd suggest using `input` event instead of `keyup`. Your protection can be overcome by pasting commas by rightclick->contextmenu->paste, which won't trigger `keyup`.

Comment: @Shyju Maybe it's some kind of spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, it is some kind of spreadsheet. Keep praying Shyju.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("input[id*=_tb]").each(function(){
        this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, "");
    }).on('keyup', function(){
        this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, "");
    });
});
```

See here for an explanation and examples of the javascript `string.replace()` function:

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-replace

as @Vega said, this doesn't write the new value back to the textbox - I updated the code to do so.

Comment: the `each` could be replaced with `$("input[id*=_tb]").val(function (_, val) { return val.replace(/,/g, ''); })`, though it won't make much of a difference in this scenario.

Comment: one should most certainly use `on('keyup', ...` as `onkeyup` is no valid jQuery method.  (see the comments on Vegas answer ;))

Answer (score 5):

Use a regex with the `g` flag instead of a string: [`.replace(/,/g, "")`](http://jsfiddle.net/GhQ4T/).

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks right except that it is not setting the value back to the input field,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[id*=_tb]")
  .each(function () {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, "")
  })
  .onkeyup(function () {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, "") 
  })
});
```

**Edit:** Used regex

Comment: @duckmike You should track back on error stack to see where the error is triggered from your code..